# Printing the sums of numbers from 1 to 10 with only 1 loop

Tags: java

The code below prints sum from 1 to 10:

> \$1\$
>   \$1+2 =\$
>   \$1+2+3 =\$
>   \$1+2+3+4 =\$
>   \$......\$
>   \$1 + ... 10 = 55\$

```
public class Solution{

    public static void print_sums(){

        int sum = 0 ;
         for(int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
             for(int j = 1 ; j <= i; j++ ){
                sum = sum + j ;
             }
             System.out.println( sum) ;
             sum = 0 ;
         }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        print_sums() ;


    }
}
```

I wonder out of "efficiency curiosity" - is it possible to do it in 1 loop?  Without 2 nested loops?

i.e. **put both `i` and `j` in one loop and increment them from there.**

I think it is impossible, because **the whole loop will run only 10 times `- i = [1,10]`

```
 for(int i = 1 , j = 1 ; j <= i && i <= 10 ; i++, j++)
             //for(int j = 1 ; j <= i; j++ ){
                sum = sum + j ;
             //}
             System.out.println( sum) ;
             sum = 0 ;
```

Comment: Clearly it is possible to do without any loops.

Comment: @emory : yes but only to calculate it once, not to print it in each step

Comment: It is a one liner   ... println(1\n3\n6\n...)    using a loop would be easier but it is not necessary.

Comment: if you do it recursively it should be fairly simple

Comment: @emory imagine the problem is `1 to N`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
public static void printSums() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        sum += i;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

The key is simply to calculate the sum of the first \$N\$ digits. It is easy if you already have the sum of the first \$N-1\$ digits : you simply add \$N\$.

Comment: And this is a good example of a primitive [form of memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: Be careful with your loop limits! And look carefully before accepting an answer!

Comment: @200_success, yes , it should be  i <=10 : less than or equal

Answer (score 14):

Another solution without the mutating `sum` temporary variable is using the \$n * (n + 1) / 2\$ formula:

```
public static void printSums() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i * (i + 1) / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: In general using the gaussian sum is better than actually calculating the sum.  In this case, I suspect the accepted answer would be more efficient.